# passing shell variable containing timestamp to SED

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a file ( *problem.txt)* where each line starts with timestamp in the format eg: 
`2014-01-05 00:00:49,908`

problem.txt contents:

```
2014-01-05 00:00:49,004 ABCDE DEF Sample1 THE END   
2014-01-05 00:00:51,037 ABCDE DEF Sample2 THE END   
2014-01-05 01:01:00,911 ABCDE DEF Sample3 THE END   
2014-01-05 01:30:49,747 ABCDE DEF sample4 THE END   
2014-01-05 02:00:00,475 ABCDE DEF sample5 THE END   
2014-01-05 03:00:00,037 ABCDE DEF sample6 THE END
```

The Task in hand is to find all lines between a given timestamp where start and end timestamp are stored in shell variables (*$searchstart0,$searchend0*).

eg:

```
searchstart0=2014-01-05 00:00:49,004   
searchend0=2014-01-05 03:00:00,037
```

Also, the result has to be stored in a text file(*results.txt*).
So, I am using the `sed` command to do the above task. Below is the command

```
sed -n "/$searchstart0/ , /$searchend0/p" problem.txt > /home/abc/results.txt
```

However, on executing the above commnad the text file generated is empty and I see the following message :

```
sed -e expression #1, char 0:no previous regular expression
```

Further, I tried executing the command using single quotes instead of double quotes but still the file generated was empty.
Please let me know if there is any possible solution to accomplish the task.

Comment: I think you need to quote the shell variables before you pass them to sed.

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? It sounds like it is more appropriate for `awk` using string comparisons with `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: Maybe your `sed` chokes on the whitespace around the comma?

Comment: @tripleee `sed` chokes on the empty start pattern, because the assignment of `searchstart0` fails. (I fixed my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `searchstart0` and `searchend0` are **empty**:

```
$ searchstart0=2014-01-05 00:00:49,004  
-bash: 00:00:49,004: command not found
$ searchend0=2014-01-05 03:00:00,037
-bash: 03:00:00,037: command not found
$ echo $searchstart0 | wc -c
   1
$ echo $searchend0 | wc -c
   1
```

Due to the error in the assignment, *nothing is assigned* to these variables. So, effectively, after the variables are evaluated, your `sed` is executed like this:

```
$ sed -n "// , //p" sample.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

This error message is raised when the first pattern is empty. The second is allowed to be empty, but then it won't do what you want, it will be as if using `$` as the end pattern, printing everything from the start pattern until the end of the file.

If you fix the variable assignments, then your script should work:

```
searchstart0='2014-01-05 00:00:49,004'
searchend0='2014-01-05 03:00:00,037'
```

And by the way you don't need spaces around the `,` in your `sed` expression, you could write like this:

```
sed -n "/$searchstart0/,/$searchend0/p" problem.txt > /home/abc/results.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your `sed` call.
Maybe you are not setting properly the two variables. Make sure you are enclosing the values between quotes since you have white spaces in the text (e.g. `searchstart0="2014-01-05 00:00:51,037"`) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If the shell variables are set correctly, the given code should work fine on the sample data because the timestamps referenced both appear in the data file:

```
searchstart0="2014-01-05 00:00:49,004"
searchend0="2014-01-05 03:00:00,037"
sed -n -e "/$searchstart0/,/$searchend0/p" problem.txt
```

Output:

```
2014-01-05 00:00:49,004 ABCDE DEF Sample1 THE END
2014-01-05 00:00:51,037 ABCDE DEF Sample2 THE END
2014-01-05 01:01:00,911 ABCDE DEF Sample3 THE END
2014-01-05 01:30:49,747 ABCDE DEF sample4 THE END
2014-01-05 02:00:00,475 ABCDE DEF sample5 THE END
2014-01-05 03:00:00,037 ABCDE DEF sample6 THE END
```

If, however, the request is for timestamps between 2014-01-05 00:00:00,000 and 2014-01-05 02:00:00,000, then the `sed` will fail to print any data.  You could approach that with `awk` using:

```
searchstart0="2014-01-05 00:00:00,000"
searchend0="2014-01-05 02:00:00,000"
awk "\$0 >= \"$searchstart0\" && \$0 < \"$searchend0\" { print }" problem.txt
```

Or, with no backslashes:

```
awk -v s0="$searchstart0" -v e0="$searchend0" '$0 >= s0 && $0 < e0 { print }' problem.txt
```

Output:

```
2014-01-05 00:00:49,004 ABCDE DEF Sample1 THE END
2014-01-05 00:00:51,037 ABCDE DEF Sample2 THE END
2014-01-05 01:01:00,911 ABCDE DEF Sample3 THE END
2014-01-05 01:30:49,747 ABCDE DEF sample4 THE END
```

This relies on the timestamps being at the beginning of the line; you have to work a little harder if the timestamp is in columns 5 and 6, say, of the data file.

(*Strictly, the `{ print }` could be omitted; `awk` provides it as the default action for a pattern. I prefer to be explicit.*)